# How do I randomize value per instance in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I'm trying to make procedural rocks with geometry nodes, but every instance of the rock has the same shape.
[image: Rocks generated with]

Is it possible to randomize vector positions of the rock for every instance, inside the gray panel ?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Ico Sphere* node creates only a single icosphere which is then instanced on the points. This is why they all look the same, they are all just duplicates of the same.

To randomize each icosphere differently you have to put the *Set Position* node *after* instancing the icosphere. But - even then they look all the same, since they are instances of one object.

To randomize them separately, you also have to add a *Realize Instances* node after the *Instance on Points* and before *Set Position*. Realizing the instances will make them all individual meshes and all be affected individually.

(Sorry I didn't recreate your complete nodetree, the essential thing here is to do it after instancing. The *Subdivision Surface* should also be put afterwards if you want to smooth the meshes. Putting it before the instancing will create more vertices to be offset randomly.)

[image: randomize instances]

Comment: Haha,I just finish my writing...Our nodes is almost the same.

Comment: @NatureK Usually I'm the one who is slower than others  :D